# Como limitar a 1 o evento de keydown em JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animação

Eu fiz um código que ao iniciar meu evento, ele faz um bloco fazer um movimento do topo até embaixo. Se ele teclar a tecla "3" entre os pixels estabelecidos durante a animação, ele faz a animação ser removida e receber "1 acerto".

Porém se eu ficar teclando toda hora, ele vai somar mais de 1 cada vez que eu ficar teclando e eu vou ter muito mais acertos que deveria. Eu gostaria se tem como limitar a somente uma vez ele poder fazer isso e bloquear nas outras, fazendo ele ter somente 1 único acerto.

No JSFiddle abaixo, no caso do alert, seria como se eu ficasse teclando o 3 várias vezes a tecla e somando os acertos. No meu código não tem alert e sim no final ele me fala os acertos
http://jsfiddle.net/m3fvL/

```
$(function cair() {
    $(".blococair").fadeTo( 500, 1 ); 
    $(".blococair").animate({
        top: fim + "px",
        },{
        duration: 5000,
        start: function () {
            inicio = window.getComputedStyle(this).top.replace('px', '');
        },
        progress: function (a, p, r) {
            var valorAtual = p * (fim - inicio);
            $(document).keyup(function(e) {
                if (e.which == 53 && Math.round(valorAtual) < 295) {
                } else if (e.which == 53 && Math.round(valorAtual) >= 296 && Math.round(valorAtual) <= 315) {
                    $('.blococair').remove();
                    acertos++;
                }})
        },


        "complete" : function() {
                      $('.blococair').remove();
        },

        start: function () {
            inicio = window.getComputedStyle(this).top.replace('px', '');

        },

    })});
```

Comment: Poderia postar um demo do JSFiddle? Vendo em execução facilita a outros dar sugestões.

Comment: Não tem como por uma condição apenas true/false, inicia a variável como false e seta como true, se true return false e não executa nada.

Comment: Feito no JSFiddle, espero que tenha ficado entendido. No caso do alert, seria como se eu ficasse teclando várias vezes a tecla e somando os acertos que no caso gostaria de limitar a 1. No meu código não tem alert e sim no final ele me fala os acertos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é que você está, no `progress`, atribuindo um *handler* novo para `keyup` a cada quadro de animação. Isso significa que, no momento em que uma tecla for pressionada, centenas de cópias idênticas do seu código vai executar, cada uma delas incrementando `acertos` - mesmo que apenas uma única tecla tenha sido pressionada.

O que você precisa fazer é adicionar esse handler somente uma vez, no `start`, e removê-lo ou no `complete` ou no momento em que uma tecla for pressionada.

```
var valorAtual; // Movi para cá, para que a função testarAcerto possa acessá-la

function testarAcerto(e) {
    if (e.which == 51 && Math.round(valorAtual) > 0) {
        $('.cair').remove();
        acertos++;
        alert(acertos);
        $(document).unbind("keyup"); // Já acertou, não ouça mais por eventos keyup
    }
}

...

    start: function () {
        inicio = window.getComputedStyle(this).top.replace('px', '');
        $(document).bind("keyup", testarAcerto); // Coloca o handler no começo
    },
    progress: function (a, p, r) {
        valorAtual = p * (fim - inicio); // Só atualiza o valor no progress
    },

    "complete": function () {
        $('.cair').remove();
        $(document).unbind("keyup"); // Remove o handler no final
    },
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/m3fvL/2/).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas é quase isso, tem que se levar em consideração que viram mais blocos atrás com a mesma tecla, no caso ela ficaria bloqueada e eu não poderia mais teclar...

Comment: @user8957 Mas quando o bloco seguinte aparecer ele vai fazer o `bind` de novo, certo? Isso deveria ser o suficiente - por exemplo, se tiver um intervalo de 5s entre um bloco e outro, e o usuário ficou apertando "3" direto, vai contar um acerto, depois ficar 5s sem registrar nada, e quando o próximo bloco aparecer vai contar um segundo acerto. Agora, se tiverem vários blocos simultaneamente, a coisa fica mais complicada...

Comment: P.S. se achar que dá pra adaptar a pergunta colocando mais detalhes, faça isso, caso contrário abra outra - pra essa não virar uma ["pergunta camaleão"...](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1115/215)

Comment: Pois é, são vários blocos de intervalo 1 segundo, como mais ou menos acontece num jogo de Guitar Hero.